# AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'ImageRecord' on <module '__main__'

Tags: python, python-2.7, error-handling

I am encountering the above error in this piece of code:

```
    for _ in tqdm(list(range(num_train_iterations))):
        batch = sess.run(train_dataloader.get_batch)
        _, train_loss_val, color_constancy_loss_val, contrastive_loss_val = \
            sess.run([train_op, train_loss, color_constancy_loss, contrastive_loss], feed_dict={
                x["images"]: batch[0],
                x["illums"]: batch[1],
                x["cc24s"]: batch[2]
```

The error line is the second line.

```
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'ImageRecord' on <module '__main__' from 'train.py'>
```

The code is downloaded from https://github.com/howardyclo/CLCC-CVPR21

I know that it does not make much sense to request browsing through the code for resolution, but I have been stuck at this for days and found no plausible solution. Any hints would be useful or any resources I can look up to get more of a clue would be welcome.

The full traceback message is shown below:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py",
> line 1365, in _do_call
>     return fn(*args)   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py",
> line 1349, in _run_fn
>     return self._call_tf_sessionrun(options, feed_dict, fetch_list,   File
> "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py",
> line 1441, in _call_tf_sessionrun
>     return tf_session.TF_SessionRun_wrapper(self._session, options, feed_dict, tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.UnknownError:
> AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'ImageRecord' on <module
> '__main__' from 'train.py'> Traceback (most recent call last):
> 
>   File
> "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\script_ops.py",
> line 244, in __call__
>     ret = func(*args)
> 
>   File
> "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\autograph\impl\api.py",
> line 302, in wrapper
>     return func(*args, **kwargs)
> 
>   File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpg9kpovk5.py", line 17,
> in _func
>     data = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(pickle).load, (ag__.ld(f),), None, fscope_1)
> 
>   File
> "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\autograph\impl\api.py",
> line 461, in converted_call
>     return _call_unconverted(f, args, kwargs, options, False)
> 
>   File
> "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\autograph\impl\api.py",
> line 340, in _call_unconverted
>     return f(*args)
> 
> AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'ImageRecord' on <module
> '__main__' from 'train.py'>
> 
> 
>          [[{{node PyFuncStateless}}]]
>          [[IteratorGetNext]]
> 
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
> 
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "train.py", line 179, in
> <module>
>     main(sess)   File "train.py", line 138, in main
>     batch = sess.run(train_dataloader.get_batch)   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py",
> line 957, in run
>     result = self._run(None, fetches, feed_dict, options_ptr,   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py",
> line 1180, in _run
>     results = self._do_run(handle, final_targets, final_fetches,   File
> "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py",
> line 1358, in _do_run
>     return self._do_call(_run_fn, feeds, fetches, targets, options,   File
> "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py",
> line 1384, in _do_call
>     raise type(e)(node_def, op, message) tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.UnknownError: AttributeError:
> Can't get attribute 'ImageRecord' on <module '__main__' from
> 'train.py'> Traceback (most recent call last):
> 
>   File
> "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\script_ops.py",
> line 244, in __call__
>     ret = func(*args)
> 
>   File
> "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\autograph\impl\api.py",
> line 302, in wrapper
>     return func(*args, **kwargs)
> 
>   File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpg9kpovk5.py", line 17,
> in _func
>     data = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(pickle).load, (ag__.ld(f),), None, fscope_1)
> 
>   File
> "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\autograph\impl\api.py",
> line 461, in converted_call
>     return _call_unconverted(f, args, kwargs, options, False)
> 
>   File
> "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\autograph\impl\api.py",
> line 340, in _call_unconverted
>     return f(*args)
> 
> AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'ImageRecord' on <module
> '__main__' from 'train.py'>
> 
> 
>          [[{{node PyFuncStateless}}]]
>          [[IteratorGetNext]]
```

Comment: Can you post the full traceback message so we get context? And, the code you show. Is it part of the top level script you ran or is it an imported module?

Comment: It seems like a top level script defined a class ImageRecord and wrote a pickle file. Now, when something else tries to load that pickle file, it attempts to find `__main__.ImageRecord`, which doesn't exist. Top level scripts shouldn't define classes to be pickled because the future unpickler must be able to import the module and find the class.

Comment: @tdelaney I have posted the full traceback message. Thanks.

Comment: I couldn't make much sense of the traceback - but this package loads a pickle file in several places. Its the pickle file that has the problem. I don't know if you supply that file or where it comes from. But the problem is in whatever wrote the pickle file. In case you are new to all this, python can serialize and save its objects using what it calls the "pickle protocol". These files record the names of modules where pickled classes are found. But top level scripts are different. Internally they are all known as `__main__` and that's where you problem is.

Comment: If you know the pickle files being used, you could open the python shell and test each one with `import pickle;pickle.load(open("some_file_name.pkl", "rb"))`. That should show the same problem.